# FB.getLoginStatus callback not get invoked on back button click in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, facebook-javascript-sdk, browser-cache

I am using facebook's js SDK. I use FB.init to initiate the fb object and FB.getLoginStatus to check user's status. Everything works fine when load the page. But when i click some link inside my page and then try to go back to my last page by clicking back button of browser FB.getLoginStatus is not get invoke the callback. This problem occurs only in Chrome's. In all other browsers it works fine.

If i clear the browser catch and then go back then everything is working fine

I also remove the all extension that may causes a problem.

Thanks in advance.